# How to plot selected lines from a hdf5 file format in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

My subcode in matplotlib  is

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

lbl = {0:'AB', 1:'BC', 2:'CD', 3:'fourth'}

for i, section in enumerate(dist):
    for nbnd, _ in enumerate(freq[i][0]):
        x = section # to_list() you may need to convert sample to list.
        y = (freq[i, :, nbnd] + offset*nbnd) * scale

        if (nbnd<3):
            color=f'C{nbnd}'
        else:
            color='black'
        ax.plot(x, y, c=color, lw=2.0, alpha=0.8, label = lbl[nbnd] if nbnd < 3 and i == 0 else None)

ax.legend()
```

It plots all data while I want to restrict to `nbnd` only (`nbnd < 3`) and want to control size of AB, BC, CD as defined in lbl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is plotting all data because your plot command is outside the `if (nbnd<3):` condition. If you only want to plot the data for `nbnd<3`, then what is the purpose of `else`? In my opinion, all you need to do is to move the plot command inside the if statement and you don't need the `else` command at all. So do the following

```
if (nbnd<3):
    color=f'C{nbnd}'
    ax.plot(x, y, c=color, lw=2.0, alpha=0.8, label = lbl[nbnd] if nbnd < 3 and i == 0 else None)
```

To change the fontsize in the legend and to control its position, you can use the following where the `loc` takes the x and the y coordinates in relative coordinates. 0 to 1 will put the legend within the plot area and anything else will put it out of the plot area.

```
plt.legend(loc=(0.5, 0.7), fontsize=20)
```

Comment: It worked for a part of question. My second part is: how to control the size of the labels associated with these three plots ( nbnd < 3) ? as defined with lbl = {0:'AB', 1:'BC', 2:'CD', 3:'fourth'}

Comment: @astha : What do you mean by size of the labels? As in fontsize?

Comment: With the restricted plot I get label to each line (here these are three as shown in the left top corner of the figure here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Rgr.png  I want to increae/decrease or relocate the position in the plot.

Comment: The problem is that I can not ask the question before 90 minutes so I added two questions in a single post. Hope you will understand it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215126/discussion-between-astha-and-sheldore).